# Operating within the file list from sub-directories in Python

Tags: python, os.walk

I have been trying to operate within individual filename contained in a list of file. Each file contains a two-column data which I want to integrate and get a value. Main folder (Main directory) contains multiple subfolders (sub-directories) named after each day. All files are in '.csv' format so I don't have to worry about selecting the specific file formats. I am trying to read the contents of each file within the sub-directories with the following code.

```
    file_path = r"C:\Users\......\Totalfiles"
    read_files = glob.glob(os.path.join(file_path,"*.csv"))

    np_array_values = []
        for (root, dirs, files) in os.walk(file_path):
            for filenames in files:
                 values = pd.read_csv(filenames, encoding='utf-8', header=0)
                 np_array_values.append(values) 
                 print(filenames)
```

There are multiple errors here. 
If I skip the second for loop, only a list containing 8 file gets printed as follows:

```
    2019-10-12-18-28.csv
    2019-10-12-18-28.csv
    2019-10-12-18-28.csv
    2019-10-12-18-28.csv
    2019-10-12-18-28.csv
    2019-10-12-18-28.csv
    2019-10-12-18-28.csv
    2019-10-12-18-28.csv
```

But if the for loop is used then the total list of 100+ files is generated. But the error is generated from the 6th line. when I try to assign a variable called values, then this error is displayed:

```
File b'2019-08-10_05-58.csv' does not exist: b'2019-08-10_05-58.csv'
```

This program runs totally fine for a directory if I don't use the first for loop. I couldn't find examples with this kind of problem (probably due to incorrect keywords used). I assume this would be useful for everyone working with loads of measurement files. Help on this would be much appreciated.

Comment: I believe you should do something like `(os.path.join(root, filenames))` instead of just `filenames` because `os.walk` truncates each part.

Comment: Please *show* the different versions of the code you are using.

Comment: Hi, I belive you are not using the correct path. The Variable "filenames" will only work if your Python's current working directory is the same of your file. You should compose the path for pd.read_csv with "dirs" and "roots", not only "filenames".

Comment: @JeromeMontino This worked. Thanks